# menu item doesn't show in ActionBar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-menu

I have tried almost all of the things suggested by SO in other questions..still menu item is not showing in action bar.
Before it used to show, but when i used action layout for menu to change the text size, it has stopped showing it.Any help will be appreciated...

This is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/mnuRecentLookUp" android:title="@string/mnuRecentLookUp" android:icon="@drawable/clock" />
<item android:id="@+id/mnuBookmarks" android:title="@string/mnuBookmarks" android:icon="@drawable/bookmarks" />
<item android:id="@+id/mnuFontSize" android:title="@string/mnuFontSize" android:icon="@drawable/fontsize"/>
<item android:id="@+id/mnuHelp" android:title="@string/mnuHelp" android:icon="@drawable/help" />

<group android:id="@+id/group_term_nav">        

          <item android:id="@+id/btnTtod"
         android:title="@string/ttod"  
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_action_layout"

         /></group>

</menu>
```

Below is menu_action_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/actionBarMenuPoints"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

   android:drawablePadding="3dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"

    />
   </FrameLayout>
```

Activity code in onCreateOptionsMenu..

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater menuInflater = this.getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_home, menu);

    // Calling super after populating the menu is necessary here to ensure
    // that the
    // action bar helpers have a chance to handle this event.
    MenuItem pointsMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.btnTtod);
   // pointsMenu.setTitle(pointsLeft );
    TextView actionBarPoints = (TextView) pointsMenu.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.actionBarMenuPoints);
    //actionBarPoints.setText(pointsLeft);
    actionBarPoints.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    actionBarPoints.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    actionBarPoints.setTextSize(20);
    //actionBarPoints.setTypeface(tfBold);
    this.getActionBar().setCustomView(actionBarPoints);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by using below code in styles.xml

```
  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
 <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle"
parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
```